# How to see who created a Windows NamedPipe

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes

Is there a way to see who **created** Windows named pipes?
I used the [Windows Sysinternal Pipelist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pipelist) but it just shows the pipes and not who created them.
I wanted to see who is the creator of each pipe on the system.

For example, I tried to see the named pipe `docker_engine_linux`. I used [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) to see who created it but it just showed me three processes that use it:

[image]

I can use [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) to search who calls `CreateNamedPipeA` but I wanted to know if there is a way to check it without hooking it, after it was created already.

Comment: file object not containing information about process which create it.

Comment: Thanks, so I will need to trace all these process. Maybe I can use it with ETW, I just need to find a suitable provider from the list https://hannahsuarez.github.io/2019/List-of-ETW-Providers/. Maybe `Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Debug` is the correct. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/etw/3399-namedpipecreated I will check.